# Replace the Boolean Characters from SQL as Text in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a data of boolean datatype values such as True/False in sql database column. I created an array of T/F using the find_by_sql (select) options. Now I need to print the array not as True/False. Instead of that I have to print "It Occurs", if data populated as True. nothing should be printed if it is false. How I can prints the alternative values of column of sql without changing the table.

TRUE = "It Occurs"
FALSE = ""

Advance Thanks Palani Kannan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working with this script,

**Table Model**

def combined_value
 if col == true
  "Conditions"
 else
  "Conditions"
 end
end

**Table View**
<% @table.each do |table| %>
<%= table.col%>

Thanks for giving ideas to everyone in this discussion

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your select statement...

```
SELECT if(column=1,"It Occurs","") as display_text FROM somethings ...
```

Or if you need to do it after the fact, use #map on the array:

```
array_as_text = array.map{|x| x ? "It Occurs" : ""}
```

Either way you should end up with something like: ["It Occurs","","","It Occurs"]

If you want to provide more details to get a clearer answer, you should do so.

Comment: I feel the Map concept will work, But, bit confused with answer. If possible give some info elaborately in array.map. If it is classified as View, Controller & Model answers, it will be clear. Thanks

Comment: array#map is a Ruby function... it's identical to array#collect, you can find it in the Ruby docs.